# What is the name the IC package which is SMD version of DIP in the same dimensions?

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount, packages

There is [an optocoupler](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/90980.pdf) which comes in DIP package. But it also has an SMD version of the DIP package. This SMD package is not SOIC, because its pin pitch size is 100mil instead of 50mil. What is the standard name of this package type?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a "standard" name for this, since in practice, it's rather rare. It's really just the same lead frame that's used for the DIP, but using a different die at the end to do the final trimming and shaping. AFAIK, each manufacturer has their own notation for this package.

Answer (score 2):

DIP style with gullwing leads

http://www.avagotech.com/pages/en/optocouplers_plastic/plastic_automotive_optocoupler/automotive_integrated_gate_drive_optocouplers/acpl-312t-000e/

http://www.analog.com/en/technical-library/packages/dip-dual-inline-package/dip-gullwing-leads/index.html

Comment: The gullwing package is also used for some DIP switches.